# Miltiple errors when compiling

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile my program with the following command:

```
gcc -Wall $(pkg-config --cflags vte-2.91) cprogram.c -o cprogram $(pkg-config --libs vte-2.91)
```

Here is the first error which I think It has to do with the following line in my code:

```
XFree(class_hint);
```

This is the first error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccu8xPYL.o: undefined reference to symbol 'XFree'
```

And here is the second error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

And here it exits with exit status 1:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm trying to compile my C program without errors, but no success.
I already checked the other answers but with no success.
I also used google but again with no success. By the way I used the -M flag and It compiled with
no errors but there wasn't output file. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XFree()` is defined in the library `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6` that you have.  Apparently you are not putting this library on the command line, which causes the first error (and perhaps the second error too).

Add `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6` at the end of your command.

If the second error is still happening, let me know, and in any case, you need to provide more information.  Make sure you provide the "SSCCE".

Comment: Yes @Mark Galeck that worked, but now getting different error. ```/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccK84u9O.o: in function `on_key_press':
term.c:(.text+0x1da): undefined reference to `dabbrev_stop'
/usr/bin/ld: term.c:(.text+0x22c): undefined reference to `dabbrev_expand'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: well, you need to supply the library where this is defined, similar to what I told you in the answer

Comment: Yes. That did the work.